# Gridview onmouseover details

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to display more information about form in on mouse over. I have written code everything with the help of google still i am not able display Please let me know where i made mistake

my aspx code is

```
<div id="divGrid" style="width: auto; float: left">
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvEdit" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="lightblue" CssClass="grid" OnRowDataBound="gvEdit_RowDataBound" FooterStyle-CssClass="footer" GridLines="None" BorderWidth="2px" PagerSettings-Visible="true" ShowFooter="true" PagerSettings-Position="Top" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvEdit_Sorting" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Record found" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="slno" OnRowCreated="gvEdit_RowCreated" OnDataBound="gvEdit_DataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvEdit_PageIndexChanging" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="50" OnRowCommand="gvEdit_RowCommand">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#086A87" ForeColor="White" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#086A87" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="DarkBlue" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#b3e5fc" ForeColor="DarkBlue" />
                    <PagerSettings Position="Top" />
                    <PagerStyle Height="65px" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="pagecounthead" />
                    <PagerTemplate>
                        <table align="center" style="width: 100%;" class="pagecounthead" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr style="background-color: #fff">
                                <td align="left" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 600; font-size: 24px; width: 15%; padding-left: 0px">Form List</td>
                                <td align="center" style="width: 45%;">
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnelred" runat="server">
                                        <table align="center" width="99%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: right; padding-left: 0px">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="First Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="First" runat="server" ID="ImgeBtnFirst" ImageUrl="../Images/First.jpg" />
                                                </td>

                                                <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: right">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Previous Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Prev" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnPrevious" ImageUrl="../Images/Previous.jpg" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="width: 25%; background-color: #fff; text-align: center">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblpageindx" CssClass="labelBold" Text="Page : " runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ToolTip="Goto Page" ID="ddlPageSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="combo_common_nowidth hide">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: left">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Next Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnNext" ImageUrl="../Images/Next.jpg" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #fff; text-align: left">
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ToolTip="Last Page" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Last" runat="server" ID="ImgbtnLast" ImageUrl="../Images/Last.jpg" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </td>
                                <td style="width: 40%; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 0px">
                                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="s" DefaultButton="Button1">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" />
                                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteCardHolderName" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtsearch"
                                            FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=" -">
                                        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Search" runat="server" CssClass="searchbtn pad" CommandName="s" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Reset" runat="server" CssClass="resetbtn" OnClick="Reset_Click" />
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </PagerTemplate>
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="form_key" HeaderText="FilingID" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" FooterStyle-CssClass="hide" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="business_key" HeaderText="BusinessKey" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hide" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" FooterStyle-CssClass="hide" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ref_no" HeaderText="Reference" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" SortExpression="ref_no" HeaderStyle-Font-Overline="false" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="fum" HeaderText="Period" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" ItemStyle-Width="8%" SortExpression="fum" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="filing_type" HeaderText="Filing Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="filing_type" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="business_name" HeaderText="Business" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" HeaderStyle-Width="16%" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="filing_status" HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" HeaderStyle-Width="11%" SortExpression="filing_status" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="borderright" HeaderText="View">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnViewDetails_Click" Text='<%#Eval("form_details")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-CssClass="nopad" FooterText="Total Number of filing" FooterStyle-CssClass="fontcolor" ItemStyle-CssClass="txtcenter" HeaderText="Schedule1" ItemStyle-Width="6.9%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <a id="wrapper1" href="Schedule12290.aspx?key=<%#Eval("form_key") %>" target="_blank">
                                    <img src="<%#Eval("schedule1") %>" alt="" class="hover" />
                                    <p class="text">Download Schedule 1</p>
                                </a>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="5%" HeaderText="Copy" HeaderStyle-CssClass="nopad" ItemStyle-CssClass="txtcenter">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDuplicate" runat="server"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/file_duplicate.png" OnClick="lnkbtnDuplicate_Click" ToolTip="Copy / Duplicate filing" CssClass='<%#Eval("duplicate") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to copy from previous years filing?');" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="3%" HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-CssClass="txtcenter" HeaderStyle-CssClass="nopad" FooterStyle-CssClass="fontcolor txtcenter">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkBtnContinue" runat="server"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/edit3.png" OnClick="imgBtnContinue_Click" ToolTip="Edit" CssClass='<%# Eval("continue")%>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="8%" HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-CssClass="txtcenter" HeaderStyle-CssClass="nopad" FooterStyle-CssClass="hide">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnDel" runat="server"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/grid/delBlue.png" OnClick="imgBtnDelete_Click" ToolTip="Delete" CssClass='<%#Eval("delete") %>' OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Do you want to delete this file permanently?');" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="line" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div runat="server" id="divDetail" onmouseover="highlight(this, event)"
            onmouseout="highlight(this, event)">
        </div>
```

javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iRowIndex;    // THE ROW INDEX OF THE GRIDVIEW, TO KEEP THE ROW HIGHLIGHTING
    // WHEN THE MOUSE IS ON ANOTHER CONTROL.

    function MouseEvents(objRef, evt, desc) {

        if (evt.type == "mouseover") {

            objRef.style.cursor = 'pointer'
            objRef.style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
            ShowDiv(desc, evt.pageY);

        }
        else {

            objRef.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
            iRowIndex = objRef.rowIndex;
            HideDiv();

        }
    }
    function ShowDiv(desc, pos) {

        // SHOW THE DIV WITH DESCRIPTIONS NEXT TO THE SELECTED GRIDVIEW ROW.

        document.getElementById('divDetail').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('divDetail').innerHTML = desc;
        document.getElementById('divDetail').style.marginTop = pos - 25 + 'px';
    }

    function HideDiv() { document.getElementById('divDetail').style.display = 'none'; }

    function highlight(objRef, evt) {
        if (evt.type == "mouseover") {
            objRef.style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('gvEdit').rows[iRowIndex].style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
        }
        else {
            if (evt.type == "mouseout") {
                document.getElementById('gvEdit').rows[iRowIndex].style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
                objRef.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
```

and my css

```
 <style type="text/css">
   body  
    {
        font-family:Arial, Tahoma;
        font-size:15px;
    }


    #divDetail  
    {
        float:left;
        font:inherit;
        font-size:13px;
        padding:2px 5px;
        width:auto;
        border:solid 2px #CCC; 
        -moz-border-radius:0 7px 7px 0; -webkit-border-radius:0 7px 7px 0; 
        border-radius:0 7px 7px 0;
        display:none;
        color:#333;
    }
    #divDetail p { 
        font:inherit; 
    }
    #divDetail a  
    {
        font:inherit;
        float:right;
        background-color:#357AE8;
        color:#FFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:solid 1px #2F5BB7; 
        border-radius:3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; 
        padding:3px; 
    }
</style>
```

and my back end **code aspx.cs**

```
 protected void gvEdit_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            String vd = System.String.Empty;
            vd = "Vehicle Details";
            Form objForm = new Form2290.Form();
            objForm.FormID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "form_key").ToString();
            BAL_F2290 objfrmkey = new BAL_F2290();
            DataTable dt = objfrmkey.getmouseover(objForm);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow ldr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    vd = vd + "Reference : " + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ref_no").ToString();
                    vd = vd + "Vin : " + dt.Rows[0]["vin"];
                    vd = vd + "Category : " + dt.Rows[0]["category"];
                    vd = vd + "Is_Logging : " + dt.Rows[0]["is_logging"];
                    vd = vd + "Is_Agricultural : " + dt.Rows[0]["is_agricultural"];
                    vd = vd + "Weight : " + dt.Rows[0]["weight_current"];
                    vd = vd + "Tax_amt : " + dt.Rows[0]["tax_amt"];
                }
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event, '" + vd + "')");
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event, '" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ref_no").ToString() + "')");

            }
        }
    }
```

**One more Important point is i am not getting any error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing it is very complicated and it really doesn't need to be this way.You can create a hidden column in your `GridView` and bind it to the required property on your datasource which contains the *details* data.Then using very minimal jQuery you can loop through the rows of the `GridView` -> extract the hidden comment -> set the tooltip of the row hover to this value or create some other event that shows a custom popup div with your comment.

Look how simple this is:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class aGridViewDetailsHover : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = this.GetUsers();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<MyUser> GetUsers()
    {
        var u1 = new MyUser { Name = "User1 Name", Surname = "User1 Surname", HiddenComment = "Hidden Comment For User 1" };
        var u2 = new MyUser { Name = "User2 Name", Surname = "User2 Surname", HiddenComment = "Hidden Comment For User 2" };
        var u3 = new MyUser { Name = "User3 Name", Surname = "User3 Surname", HiddenComment = "Hidden Comment For User 3" };

        return new List<MyUser> { u1, u2, u3 };
    }

}

public class MyUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string HiddenComment { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hiddencol { display: none; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#GridView1 tr').each(function () {
                var tr = $(this);
                var children = $(tr).children();
                var commentTd = children[2];
                var comment = $(commentTd).html();

                if (comment != "")
                {
                    $(tr).prop("title", comment);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HiddenComment" ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```